# onClick not waiting for a Click Javascript

Tags: javascript

I made a button that is supposed to start changing the color of some text every couple of seconds. The code DOES change color, but it happens right when the page is loaded, and doesn't wait for the user to click the button for it to change color. Here is my code. Please explain to me and show me how to make the code only execute when the user clicks the button.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<style>
#woo{
color: green;
}

#woot{
color: orange;
}
</style>

<button onClick="onChange()">SWAG</button>
<p id="woo">WAM</p>


<script>
setInterval(function(){onChange()}, 2000);


function onChange(){
    document.getElementById("woo").id = "woot";
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("woot").id = "woo";
    }, 1000);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you can help answer my question, please do.

Comment: You're executing `onChange()` in a `setInterval()` when the page loads, so there's no reason it would wait for user action.

Comment: Like @cookiemonster you are _explicitly_ asking it to do this. This is what `setInterval(function(){onChange()}, 2000);` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you call `setInterval()` you ask the browser to execute `onChange()` every 2 seconds, regardless of the button.

Try something like:

```
<style>
    #woo.green {
        color: green;
    }

    #woo.orange {
        color: orange;
    }
</style>

<button onClick="startChange()">SWAG</button>
<p id="woo" class="orange">WAM</p>
<script>
    var intervalRef;
    var green = false;

    function startChange() {
        intervalRef = setInterval(function() { doChange(); }, 1000);
    }

    function stopChange() {
        clearInterval(intervalRef);
    }

    function doChange() {
        var el = document.getElementById("woo");
        if (green) {
             el.className = "orange";
             green = false;
        } else {
             el.className = "green";
             green = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove the call to `setInterval`. Your `onclick` handler is fine. See this example, where I deleted the `setInterval` call:

http://jsfiddle.net/U6Z8F/